# Изменить значение у всех полей

Tags: mysql

В базе данных есть INT поля slot_1, slot_2, slot_3 и так далее. Как можно у всех этих полей изменить значение? Похожее на `slot_%` есть?

Comment: `Похожее на slot_% есть?`. Нет. Делаешь именно Update и дальше SET для каждого поля

Comment: Там просто 180 полей

Comment: 180 полей - означает, что в структуре БД что-то не так. Значит там понапихано всё что не попадя. Такую БД либо надо выкидывать, либо срочняком переделывать. В целом - это уже ваша проблема, что там 180 полей. Другого способа нет, разве что делать дамп, в текстовом файле регуляркой поменять, а потом залить дамп обратно.

Comment: Эта таблица - инвентарь игрока на 180 предметов

Comment: Где 180 слотов? Еще раз скажу - некорректно это сделано. Например сделать таблицу **тип** инвентаря, сделать данные по тому, сколько слотов может занимать инвентарь, на какие слоты может вставать, какому игроку и т.д. и всё это увязать. 180 слотов - это решение полностью неправильное.

Comment: В новом проекте это реализовано через 2 поля. А тот сделан очень давно, и переписывать его нет ни желания ни времени

Comment: Мне лично всё равно. Суть не изменить - SET для каждого поля. Тчк

Comment: Неужели нет (slot_1, slot_2, ..., slot_180)? А как всем полям поставить одинаковое значение, кроме поля KEY?

Answer (score 0):

```
function updateSlotQuery($key, array $slotValues) 
{
    $sqlPart[] = "`KEY`='{$key}'";
    foreach ($slotValues as $k=>$v) {
        $sqlPart[] = "`slot_{$k}`='{$v}'";
    }

    return "UPDATE table SET " . implode(',', $sqlPart);
}

$slotValues = array_fill(1, 180, 0);

echo updateSlotQuery('50',$slotValues );
```

Comment: Привет) Вероятно `KEY` планировалось добавить в `WHERE`?

Comment: @vp_arth Привет)), все может быть. Какое тз, такое хз